# Is it common to omit "it's" in spoken American?

Tags: pronunciation

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/q7SAt9h4sd0?t=841)

> **it's** just time to move on

It sounds like "it's" is completely omitted. Is it common in spoken American?

Comment: It's not omitted. I can hear clearly. She is emphasizing 'just time' more.

Comment: @kevin012 Thank you. You're referring the original actor rather than the tutor, right?